# how to wrap data inside highchart using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I am trying to display customer registration info. I am wrapping the data and passing inside the highchart, but the data what I am passing is not getting displayed. Any help/advice greatly appreciated.

Angularjs:

```
.controller('ctrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){            
  $http({
    url: '//customerinformation',
    method: 'GET'
  })
  .then(
    function successCallback(response){
        $scope.users = response.data.customers;
        loadChartData(response.data.customers);
    },
    function errorCallback(response){
        console.log('Error:' + response.data);
  });


  function loadChartData(data) {
      $scope.chartOptions =  {
        chart: { type: 'column' },
        title: { text: 'Customer Information' },
        xAxis: { categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar','Apr','May','June','July','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'] },
        yAxis: { title: { text: 'No.of customer' } },
        series: [{ 
         name: 'customer', 
         data: data 
        }]
      };
  }    
}])
```

Comment: Could you show your `response.data.customers` details? Maybe format is wrong? It should be array of points, where values are numbers.

Comment: You can simpally push your response data into a new array and use that array in your data .

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/IXozG3jHOfr88zzapPhe?p=preview @PawełFus

Comment: I tried pushing through array, but it din't worked @sahil0021

Comment: You have to close your callback method after the loadChartData method. maybe this link help [link](http://www.knowstack.com/webtech/charts_demo/highchartsdemo4.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide format supported by Highcharts. `customers` and `months` means nothing :)

Use `x`, `y`, `name` etc. properties (details: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data ).

You can simply map your data: `data: data.map(point => [point.month, point.customers])` or `data: data.map(point => { name: point.month, y: point.customers })`

Now you can remove categories from xAxis and set `type`: `xAxis: { type: 'category' }`